# Use data binding on multiple controls

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a `CheckBox` which I would like to control the `Enabled` property of all `TextBoxes` in a form. I would like to do this, using `DataBinding`. Is there a way I can create a single `DataBinding` which I can use for every `TextBox` in the form?

```
// Creating the binding for the checkbox
Binding bindDisableFormFields = new Binding("Checked", viewModel, "DisableFormFields");

 // Create the binding for the textboxes
Binding bindIsFormEnabled = new Binding("Enabled", viewModel, "IsFormEnabled");

// Add the binding to the checkbox. This works as intended
myForm.DisableFormCheckBox.DataBindings.Add(bindDisableFormFields);

// Add bindings and textboxes. After adding the binding 
// to the first textbox, the code will fail at runtime. So obviously
// this is not a useful approach.    
myForm.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(bindIsFormEnabled);
myForm.TextBox2.DataBindings.Add(bindIsFormEnabled);  // This line will fail
myForm.TextBox3.DataBindings.Add(bindIsFormEnabled);
myForm.TextBox4.DataBindings.Add(bindIsFormEnabled);
myForm.TextBox5.DataBindings.Add(bindIsFormEnabled);
```

Comment: you can put your TextBoxes into List then bind in a loop

Comment: That is not a bad idea. However, is there no way to use the same binding mulitple times? Afterall it is the exact same binding I would like them to use?

Comment: i'd suggest you use WPF

Comment: @LeiYang I suggested that as well, when the project began. But this wasn't really my decission, so I have to work with what I got (WinForms).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not create a new Binding each? :

```
myForm.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", viewModel, "IsFormEnabled"));
myForm.TextBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", viewModel, "IsFormEnabled"));
myForm.TextBox3.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", viewModel, "IsFormEnabled"));
myForm.TextBox4.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", viewModel, "IsFormEnabled"));
myForm.TextBox5.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", viewModel, "IsFormEnabled"));
```

Or in a more elegant approach:

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>() { myForm.TextBox1, myForm.TextBox2, myForm.TextBox3, myForm.TextBox4, myForm.TextBox5 };

textBoxes.ForEach(t => t.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Enabled", viewModel, "IsFormEnabled")));
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution available. It look slightly less elegant in my actual code, as the names here are a bit longer :-).